# Annotation version of ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> and similar interfaces

Tags: java, spring, cxf

You can use code like the following to do some events based on when your web service is shut down (or refreshed/started).

```
public class APIService implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent contextClosedEvent) {
        //Do shutdown work.
    }
}
```

I was told that there is an annotation driven way to do this that does not require you to implement this interface.  Specifically, you should be able to define a function with any name you like and annotate it so that it executes on service start-up or shut-down.

I'm having trouble finding references to this in my spring book or via google though.  Can someone provide an example of how to do the above code via annotations alone?

Comment: Did they tell you if this was part of Spring Core or part of some other Spring library? I have not heard of such a feature in Spring Core.

Comment: Unfortunately they didn't and they're left work for the day already.  I'll follow up with them if someone hasn't figured it out by tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as [the Spring 4+ documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) is concerned, there is no such feature exactly as you describe it.

You can simulate the behavior with

```
@Component // defaults to eager initialization
class Setup {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void anyNameYouWant() {
        System.out.println("starting");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void hereToo() {
        System.out.println("closing");
    }
}
```

But you won't have access to the `ContextClosedEvent`, nor the full range of `ApplicationContextEvent`s.

Comment: I think this is what they were referring to after doing a fair amount of searching myself as well.  Thank you for the nice sample :).

Answer (score 0):

`@EventListener` introduced in Spring 4.2 [Here you go](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events-annotation)