# Spring webapp - shutting down threads on Application stop

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am instantiating a ScheduledExecutorService using Spring's ApplicationListener interface as follows:

```
@Component
public class ExecutorsStart implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

@Autowired
Scheduler scheduler;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.init();
    int delay = 10;
    int period = 60;// repeat every 1 minutes.
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduler, delay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

At the moment, Tomcat won't shut down cleanly when I run, ./shutdown.sh, with message:

```
The web application [/foo] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it
```

and this seems to be because I have not yet written code to stop the ScheduledExecutorService.

My question is: how should this be done properly in this environment?

I noticed that there exists a [ContextStoppedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStoppedEvent.html), so, I implemented a listener for it:

```
@Component
public class ExecutorsStop implements ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent> {

@Autowired
ExecutorsStart executorsStart;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextStoppedEvent event) {
    executorsStart.executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

But it seems that this event handler doesn't get called when Tomcat is shutdown.

Have I implemented this incorrectly, or am I going about this completely the wong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `ContextClosedEvent`.

```
@Component
public class ExecutorsStop implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    ExecutorsStart executorsStart;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextClosedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Stopped: " + event);
    }
}
```

When the Servlet container shuts down, it calls `contextDestroyed(..)` on its various `ServletContextListener` and `destroy()` on its `Servlet` instances. The `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` each call [`close()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#close--) on their `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Is the PreDestroy annotation you mention in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22544982/55070 not enough for doing so?