# How can I perform an operation when a Spring application ends?

Tags: java, spring

I am not so into Spring framework and I have the following problem.

I am implementing a simple console application (it is a batch that obtain some data from a database and perform some call to an external web service).

When the application starts it creates a lock file in the same folder where the executed .jar file is.

**My problem is: when the application ends this lock file have to be deleted.**

**This must be done either when the application terminates successfully or when it terminates for an error.**

I read that in Java I can use a **ShutdownHook** but I am thinking that maybe Spring provide me some more neat way to do it.

So basically I have a situation like this:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            checkIfRunning();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            new MainApp().execute();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    private void execute() throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Trigger BATCH START");

        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(150);

        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("applicationContext.xml");
        context.refresh();

        System.out.println("OBTAINED CONTEXT");
        System.out.println("Trigger BATCH END");

    }

    /**
     * Check if the Trigger batch is alread running:
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    private static void checkIfRunning() throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("checkIfRunning() START");

        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lock.txt");

        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
            System.out.println("Lock file exists !!!");
        }
        else {
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lock.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
        }

    }
}
```

How can I correctly intercept the event related to the application termination to perform the delete of my lock file?

The application can terminate because:

- **It completed its execution.**
- **The user press CTRL+C and quit it.**
- **An exception occur and it terminate.**

What is a smart way to do it using Spring?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936162/register-shutdownhook-in-web-application

Comment: Instead of creating a file, you could just open a socket on a given port.

Comment: @JBNizet No I can't, I want but I can't (my boss says no)

Comment: Try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650569/spring-webapp-shutting-down-threads-on-application-stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650569/spring-webapp-shutting-down-threads-on-application-stop)

Comment: @ChristianZiegler it is not a webapp !!!

Answer (score -1):

Since the file creation happens outside of Spring, I would delete it outside of Spring for consistency.

You can add a shutdown hook:

```
try {
    checkIfRunning();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Deleting the lock file...");
            // TODO: call a function to delete the lock file if it exists
            System.out.println("Lock file delete");
        }
    });
}
```

According the documentation: [`addShutdownHook(Thread hook)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)):

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

Comment: Why the negative vote? If the file creation happens in Spring as a post context creation event, it makes sense to use the symmetric destroy event to delete the files. Otherwise, I maintain the file destruction should happen outside of the Spring context.

Comment: The downvote is not mine. A questions: using this way what happens if the user terminates the program (CTRL+C)? The filw will be deleted?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer